# Remove ngIf item on dual conditions

Tags: angular

I would like to call the method `onRemoveLastTag()` with dual conditions.
I want to call the method only when the form is empty and `keyup.backspace`.

Backspace should operate normally while there is still text in the input field. This is an Angular 11 application.

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <label for="search"></label>
  <span class="chippie"
        *ngFor="let tag of selectedTags; let i=index">
    {{tag}}
    <a class="close"
       (click)="onRemoveTag(i)"
    > X</a></span>

  <input
    id="search"
    formControlName="search"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Your tag goes here"
    class="form-control"
    autocomplete="off"
    (keyup.enter)="addTag($event)"
    (keyup.backspace)="onRemoveLastTag()"
    (keyup)="openDropdown()"
    (keyup.arrowLeft)="toggleDropdown()"
    >
</form>
```

```js
onRemoveLastTag() {
  this.selectedTags.pop();
  console.log(this.selectedTags)
}
```

Comment: try this `(keyup.backspace)="!$event.target.value && onRemoveLastTag()"`

Comment: The answer is technically correct, but I still have some other adverse behaviour.  So the logic required for the desired behaviour is more easily solved with a typescript method. Once I have it working I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I tried to build logic into the HTML. I believe it's best practice to keep the logic in TypeScript. Here is the method I used to handle the logic.

```js
onBackspace() {
  if (!this.getSearchValue()) {
    if (!this.isSelectingAndRemovingTags) {
      this.isSelectingAndRemovingTags = true;
      return;
    }
    if (this.toBeRemovedTagIndex < 0) {
      this.toBeRemovedTagIndex = this.selectedTags.length - 1;
      return;
    }
    this.onRemoveTag(this.toBeRemovedTagIndex);
    this.toBeRemovedTagIndex = this.selectedTags.length - 1;
  }
}
```